# change attr value of dom element copied in variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a dom.

```
 <div id="abc">
  <svg width="240" height="200"></svg>
  <svg width="240" height="200"></svg>
  <svg width="240" height="200"></svg>
 </div>
```

I am copying this in a variable.

```
var target = document.getElementById('abc');
```

Now i want to change the width/height of all svg tags to 100% instead of 240/200.
How can i do it. This is what i tried.......

```
    var $elem = $('<div>').html(target);
    var $img = $elem.find('svg');
    for (i = 0; i < $img.length; i++) {
        console.log($img[i]);
        $img[i].css('height', '100%');
        $img[i].css('width', '100%');
    }
```

Comment: any error........? what console says?

Comment: In comments you say “i dnt want to change the dom....just in variable”, in the question you say “change the width/height of all svg tags”, and you have accepted an answer that shows (as the first suggestion) how to set CSS properties on the elements. Please make up your mind on what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to call css on `DOM` object as *indexer* on jquery object collection gives `DOM` object, you should use [eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq/%E2%80%8E) to get jQuery object to call `css` on it

```
var $elem = $('<div>').html(target);
var $img = $elem.find('svg');
for (i = 0; i < $img.length; i++) {
    console.log($img[i]);
    $img.eq(i).css('height', '100%');
    $img.eq(i).css('width', '100%');
}
```

**Edit**: based on comments.

Using css will effect the style attribute of the element. You would probably need attr instead of css to set height and width attributes.

```
$img.eq(i).attr('height', '100%');
$img.eq(i).attr('width', '100%');
```

Or try removing the attributes width and height using removeAttr and then using `css()`

```
$img.eq(i).removeAttr('height');
$img.eq(i).removeAttr('width');
$img.eq(i).css('height', '100%');
$img.eq(i).css('width', '100%');
```

**Suggestion:** Use each is more straightforward solution here as Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy pointed.

```
$img.each(function() {      
    $(this).css('height', '100%');
    $(this).css('width', '100%');
});
```

Comment: your answer is correct...i dnt know who did -1...+1 from my side

Comment: but the thing is its making <svg width="240" height="200" style="width:100%;height:100%;"></svg>

Comment: Try using like, $img.eq(i).attr('width', '100%');

Comment: Please also suggest him using .each() in this context.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
$('#abc > svg')
.removeAttr('width height')
.css({"height":"100%","width":"100%"});
```

Comment: @shaleen, what do you mean when you say what you say

Answer (score 0):

I think this would suffice

```
$('#abc > svg').css({"height":"100%","width":"100%"});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#abc svg").css({"width":"100%" , "height":"100%" });
```

Comment: How does that add on to my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/)** to loop through `svg` elements inside `#abc` div along with **[.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)** to change the width and height attribute:

```
$('#abc svg').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('width', '100%');
    $(this).attr('height', '100%');
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3FLaA/)**

Answer (score 0):

You are applying height in percentage which will work for ie only but for other browsers you need to make sure it's parent div is set to some fixed height in pixels.

For eg. to make this work just add the following css:

```
html,body{height: 100%;}
```